# ¿Cómo seleccionar el hijo de una clase en javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo esta clase en CSS:

```
nav a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
}
```

Y me gustaría cambiar el atributo `color` desde javascript dentro de un `eventListener`, sin embargo no sé cómo seleccionar esa clase desde javascript y cambiar el valor del atributo.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de HTML que contenga un hijo para hacer la prueba?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando te refieres a "nav a" no son clases (las clases en css empiezan por .), en este caso son elementos del DOM (refiriendose a los nombres de etiquetas) en la jerarquía padre e hijo, entonces la selección y asignación de color sería:

```
document.querySelector('nav a').style.color = "rgb(1, 2, 3)"
```

Si es que solo quieres cambiar un único elemento entonces se seleccionará el primero que cumpla la coincidencia de jerarquía padre < nav > e hijo < a >.

En caso quieras cambiar de color a todas las coincidencias con tal jerarquía de selección entonces seleccionarías todas con:

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav a')
```

Esto seleccionará una lista de elementos con la jerarquía indicada, entonces para cambiar la propiedad color tendrías que iterar la lista y aplicar el cambio uno por uno con:

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav a').forEach(e => e.style.color = "rgb(1, 2, 3)")
```

Answer (score 5):

Tienes dos opciones para llevar a cabo tu tarea:

- Sobreescribir el atributo CSS `color` en cada elemento que coincida con ese selector.
- Modificar el atributo CSS en la hoja de estilos.

### Modificar los elementos por selector

```js
let cambiar = () => {
  /* Iteramos por cada elemento que coincida con el selector CSS */
  document.querySelectorAll('nav a').forEach((elemento) => {
    /* Cambiamos el atributo CSS del elemento */
    elemento.style.color = "red";
  });
};
```

```css
nav a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="cambiar()">Cambiar estilo</button>
<nav><a href="#">Hola</a></nav>
```

### Modificar la hoja de estilos

```js
let cambiar = () => {
  /* Iteramos por cada hoja de estilos del documento */
  for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    /* Iteramos por cada regla CSS de la hoja de estilos */
    for (let j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
      /* Si el selector de la regla coincide con la que buscamos, la cambiamos */
      if (document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].selectorText == 'nav a') {
        /* Cambiamos el estilo de la regla del selector encontrado */
        document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].style.color = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
nav a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="cambiar()">Cambiar estilo</button>
<nav><a href="#">Hola</a></nav>
```

Comment: Interesante, pensaba que no se podía acceder a la hoja de estilos desde javascript

Comment: El único problema es, @blonfu , que no se pueden iterar con forEach ninguna de las dos matrices.